# How to update with the multiples records in mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

here i want to update with the multiple records so i'm using bulk operations and im trying to set the `isenrolledcourse` to true but its not updating

what i'm passing wrong here, thanks in advance

`idsList = [ 60f6897c3b996238808ca5e2, 60f6f729012963152c7d0a0b ]`

```
 const Course = db.courses;
 Course.bulkWrite([
    { updateMany :
       {
          "filter" : { _id : {$in : idsList }},
          "update" : { $set: { "isenrolledcourse": true}},    
          "upsert" : true,
       }
    }
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

`updateMany` would do, you do not need `bulkWrite`, because you are doing single kind of action i.e. update. `bulkWrite` is used to carry on different kinds of actions together.

```
Course.updateMany(
  {_id : {$in : idsList }},
  {$set: { "isenrolledcourse": true}},
  {upsert:true}
)
```

Comment: its still not updating

Comment: where are you extcuting? mongo shell?

Comment: you are not using mongoose?

Comment: im using mongoose

Comment: then `const Course = db.courses;` wont work. You need to create schema and then use it. Did you create schema?

Comment: Can you update your question with the schema

Comment: its worked, actually  $set `isenrolledcourse` value i'm giving wrong